# How do I fix my sass compilation error: expected selector

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, compilation, selector

First time here, so **sorry** for any lack of understanding in the code of conduct of this place.

I've already read the post with a **similar described problem**, but it **didn't help** :-/ 
Sorry, I'm a n00b, be gentle!

Just started structuring my sass into different files, and at the same time started using sass instead of scss.

**My problem**, which is probably really simple and stupid, is:

```html
Compilation Error
Error: Invalid CSS after "...align: top; } }": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
        on line 43 of Users/Test/Documents/walters.dk 6.0/styles/1-base/_typography.sass
        from line 2 of Users/Test/Documents/walters.dk 6.0/styles/1-base/_base-dir.sass
        from line 2 of sass/Users/Test/Documents/walters.dk 6.0/styles/app.sass
>>         vertical-align: top; } } {
```

**The file the error is originating from looks like this:**
(Line 43 is the bottom one, "vertical-align: top")

```html
// Text

h1 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif
    font-weight: 300
    display: inline-block
    color: $redish
    margin: 0 auto
    text-align: center
    font-size: 25px
    line-height: 1


h2 
    font-family: 'waltershand', Arial, sans-serif
    text-align: center
    font-size: 10rem
    margin-top: 3%
    


h3 
    font-family: 'waltershand', Arial, sans-serif
    text-align: center


h4 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif
    font-size: 0.85rem
    font-weight: 600
    display: inline-block


h5 
    font-size: 3rem
    font-family: 'waltershand', Arial, sans-serif
    margin: 4vh 5vw auto 5vw
    z-index: 2
    
    +mq(875px)
        font-size: 4.4vw
        display: inline-block
        vertical-align: top
```

First time using mixins, so in case it helps, i have added the code below :

```html
=mq($size)
    @media only screen and (min-width: $size)
        @content
```

The files compile into app.sass like this:

```html
@import 'variables'
@import '1-base/base-dir'
```

I'm guessing the problem isn't in the actual line 43, but rather in the way my mixin is written, or the way its importet.

Here's hoping some brainy code master can help!

Comment: I don't get any error when I try to compile your code. I only managed to get the same error as you when I tried to compile it as SCSS instead of SASS. Are your sure that your compiler has the right configuration?

Answer (score 0):

By removing this

```
+mq(875px)
        font-size: 4.4vw
        display: inline-block
        vertical-align: top
```

Your code is good to go. I'm not sure about the `mq` what does it do ?

You can cleary see the error and try it out [here](http://beautifytools.com/sass-compiler.php)

[image]
    Error: no mixin named mq

> Backtrace:
>         stdin:38
>           on line 38 of stdin
>        @include mq(875px) {    -------------^

Comment: `mq` is a mixin declared with the [shorthand sass syntax](https://alligator.io/sass/sass-mixins-shorthand/#the-code---after). Removing it is not a solution.